# Identify the latest file from a file list

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sftp

I have a pretty tricky task (at least for me).

I have an sftp access to a server which I need to get ONLY the latest file in the directory. Since sftp interface is very limited I have come up to list the files in the directory to a text file first.

This is the code

```
sftp -b - hostname >list.txt <<EOF
ls -l *.xls
EOF
```

My concern now is from list.txt, how do I identify the latest file?

Sample content of list.txt

```
cat list.txt

-rw-r--r--    0 16777221 16777216    52141 Mar 29 08:06 samplefile1.xls
-rw-r--r--    0 16777221 16777216  2926332 Mar 28 09:48 samplefile2.xls
-rw-r--r--    0 16777221 16777216    40669 Mar 26 04:38 samplefile3.xls
-rw-r--r--    0 16777221 16777216     8640 Mar 19 08:02 samplefile4.xls
-rw-r--r--    0 16777221 16777216   146331 Mar 25 07:27 samplefile5.xls
-rw-r--r--    0 16777221 16777216    18988 Mar 19 03:53 samplefile6.xls
-rw-r--r--    0 16777221 16777216    36640 Apr  2 12:52 samplefile7.xls
```

Comment: `ls -lt` can be used to list files by last modified date.

Comment: Maybe you have control of the server and can get it to generate a symbolic link called `latest` which it always points to the newest file whenever it creates one?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ls -lt`

```
sftp -b - hostname >list.txt <<EOF
ls -lt
EOF
```

Now the first line in your file will be latest file.

Comment: for some reason if I add .xls in ls -lt , it doesnt sort the file correctly.
sftp -b - hostname >list.txt <<EOF
ls -l *.xls
EOF

Comment: What output u are getting from `ls -lt *.xls`

Comment: It is not sorted in anyway by the latest file. I don't see any particular pattern how it is sorted.

Comment: `find . -type f  -name "*.xls" -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1` other option would be `find`. This will give you onyl the file that is created in past 24 Hours.

Comment: Other option would be after retrieving files using a script (python/perl) to get the desired output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168092/discussion-between-rehan-azher-and-user2058738).

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it like below:-

1. Maintain a history file in your server like history.txt
2. Before transferring file create a list of files that you are creating at the moment.

For the first time generate a history.txt file manually and add all the files that you have already transferred. For example samplefile6.xls and samplefile7.xls

```
sftp -b - hostname >list.txt <<EOF
ls -l *.xls
EOF
```

Now add a while loop to your above existing script

```
while read line
do
   file=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $9}')
   if grep "$file" history.txt; then
      echo "File already existed in history file -- No need to transfer"
   else
      sftp server_host <<EOF
      cd /your/dropLocation
      put $file
      quit
      EOF
      echo "$file" >> history.txt
      #add the transferred file to history file
   fi
 done < list.txt
```

With this approach, even if you have more than one latest files you can transfer them very easily.

Hope this will help you.